# Python: win32com: Library not registered

Tags: python, com, win32com

I am using `win32com` in python to access a native C++ COM dll. I registered my COM component (SysWOW64/regsvr32 my.dll) and called `makepy.py -i`. In .py-code, I got the module and an instance from the class I need.
Now when calling a method from this object I get an error in the auto-generated file from `makepy`:
My function got enumerated, and in the generated file, there is the following statement:

```
def MyFunction(self):
    'method MyFunction'
    return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(14, LCID, 1, (24, 0), (),)
```

So this is calling the actual COM method. But it fails:
   `pywintypes.com_error: (-2147319779, 'Library not registered.', None, None)`
Do I need an additional registration?
`combrowse.py` shows my object and the windows registry is okay.

Comment: It will be easier to get answers not only where the error occurred but also where the object was created and related variables and constants. 
For example, it is probable that they are not created properly, or simply 64-bit python is running. 
Besides, start up in debug mode and try one step execution etc.

Comment: My python is 32 bit, also win32com.
platform.architecture() gives me also 32bit.

I can access the object in .Net/C# with platform=x86. Everything works fine there.

Comment: If so, are there any shortages or problems with your application? 
If your question is added to the source code of the application related to them, there may be people who can check it and answer it.